# Access Removing CERTAIN PARTS of Duplicates in Union Query

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, ms-access-2007, union

I'm working in Access 2007 and know nothing about SQL and very, very little VBA.  I am trying to do a union query to join two tables, and delete the duplicates.

BUT, a lot of my duplicates have info in one entry that's not in the other.  It's not a 100% exact duplicate.

Example,
Row 1: A, B, BLANK
Row 2: A, BLANK, C

I want it to MERGE both of these to end up as one row of A, B, C.

I found a similar question on here but I don't understand the answer at all.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I don't know enough about SQL right now to know what I'm doing.  Also we're going a different direction with the database at work.  I really thank you for your help and one day I hope to understand it :)

Comment: No problem, I hope your direction is moving away from access. :) Best of luck to you.

Comment: what should I be using/learning instead of access?  I've already gotten this comment a lot and would love to know what's better.  Thanks!

Comment: Access is great if you are mocking up a database, or building a proof of concept maybe? .. but it does not scale well and as you can see does not conform to ANSI sql specs.  If you are in the microsoft world, try SQL Server.  There is a free edition available to start out.  MySql is another popular alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a query like this:

```
select
  coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) as a,
  coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b,
  coalesce(t1.c, t2.c) as c
from
  table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
```

Here, I have used the keyword `coalesce`.  This will take the first non null value in a list of values.  Also note that I have used `key` to indicate the column that is the same between the two rows.  From your example it looks like `A` but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Thank you, do I implement this with VBA or in the SQL view of the union query?

Comment: @msim You would use this in the sql view *in lieu of* the union query.

Comment: I'm finally getting a chance to try this.  Do i need to change "t1" and "t2" to the names of my tables?  I used A, B, C for the example but my fields have names, so do I need to put those in [] brackets?  All the columns I'm joining are the same, so does that affect the key value?  Sorry for the numerous questions, I'd love to gain a better understanding of all of this.  Thanks again.

Comment: @msim t1 and t2 are aliases.  They dont need to change, just change `table1` and `table2` to your table names.  You shouldnt need brackets unless you have a table or column name that has spaces in it (those should be avoided).  If every column could have a null value in it, then you probably need to take it in parts, handling each column individually.

Answer (score 0):

If your first table has all the key values, then you can do:

```
select t1.a, nz(t1.b, t2.b), nz(t1.c, t2.c) as c
from table1 as t1 left join
     table2 as t2
     on t1.a = t2.a;
```

If this isn't the case, you can use this rather arcane looking construct:

```
select t1.a, nz(t1.b, t2.b), nz(t1.c, t2.c) as c
from table1 as t1 left join
     table2 as t2
     on t1.a = t2.a
union all
select t2.a, t2.b, t2.c
from table2 as t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 as t1 where t1.key = t2.key)
```

The first part of the union gets the rows where there is a key value in the first table.  The second gets the rows where the key value is in the second but not the first.

Note this is much harder in Access than in other (dare I say "real") databases.  MS Access doesn't support common table expressions (CTEs), `union`s in subqueries, or `full outer join` -- all of which would help simplify the query.